# Java Thymeleaf: Could not parse expression

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have faced with the error:

```
Could not parse as expression: "${consultation.getStatus().toString()}!=SCHEDULED && consultation.getStatus().toString()}!=RECEIVED"
```

In the line :

```
<span th:if="${consultation.getStatus().toString()}!=SCHEDULED &amp;&amp; consultation.getStatus().toString()}!=RECEIVED" th:text="${consultation.getStatus()}"></span>
```

i cannot figure out why Thymeleaf is complaining?

Update:
I am trying to check an attribute if it is equal to `SCHEDULED`  or `RECEIVED`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${...}` means that you want to evaluate expression. You should only have one expression in yout `th:if` tag. Also logical and is not `&&` but just word `and`.

Change it as below and it should start working:

```
${consultation.getStatus().toString()!='SCHEDULED' and consultation.getStatus().toString()!='RECEIVED'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
${consultation.getStatus().toString() ne 'SCHEDULED'; and consultation.getStatus().toString() ne 'RECEIVED'}
```

Comment: what is "ne" operation?

Comment: Ne - not equals